# Generate parameter annotations in Byte Buddy

Tags: java, annotations, byte-buddy

I would like to use ByteBuddy to generate simple interfaces like this:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    void myMethod(@Deprecated String myDeprecatedParameter);
}
```

This is just an example, but the point is that the parameters of the methods need a number of custom annotations.
Does anyone have a simple example that would demonstrate how to achieve this in ByteBuddy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an interface with an annotated parameter like the following. First define the interface name and modifiers, then define the method with it's name, return type and modifiers and finally the parameters and annotations if have any.

```
Class<?> myInterface = new ByteBuddy()
        .makeInterface()
        .name("MyInterface")
        .modifiers(Visibility.PUBLIC, TypeManifestation.ABSTRACT)
        .defineMethod("myMethod", void.class, Visibility.PUBLIC)
        .withParameter(String.class, "myDeprecatedParameter")
        .annotateParameter(AnnotationDescription.Builder.ofType(Deprecated.class)
                .build())
        .withoutCode()
        .make()
        .load(this.getClass().getClassLoader())
        .getLoaded();
```

You can call `annotateParameter(...)` many times if you need multiple annotations.

After the `make()` method you get the unloaded class, just load the class and use it.

Here are some prints with the reflection api of the interface class.

```
System.out.println(Modifier.toString(myInterface.getModifiers())); // public abstract interface
System.out.println(myInterface.getSimpleName()); // MyInterface
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myInterface.getDeclaredMethods())); // [public abstract void MyInterface.myMethod(java.lang.String)]

Method method = myInterface.getDeclaredMethod("myMethod", String.class);
System.out.println(method.getName()); // myMethod
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(method.getParameters())); // [java.lang.String myDeprecatedParameter]

Parameter parameter = method.getParameters()[0];
System.out.println(parameter); // java.lang.String myDeprecatedParameter
System.out.println(parameter.getName()); // myDeprecatedParameter
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parameter.getAnnotations())); // [@java.lang.Deprecated()]

Annotation annotation = parameter.getAnnotations()[0];
System.out.println(annotation); // @java.lang.Deprecated()
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick and concise answer, @JoseDaSilva. My mistake was that I used `DynamicType.Builder.define(Method)` instead of `defineMethod(...)`, which did not offer `annotateParameter(...)`. Your code gave me the crucial hint that I was missing. I ended up using `annotateParameter(Annotation...)`, which allowed me to also have annotations with parameters, as well as passing multiple annotations in a single call.

Comment: You're welcome, this library is great even though examples like this are hard to find in the official documentation.